# how to add navigation icons in specific template?

Tags: plugins, multisite, themes, search, theme-customizer

I am developing a website for real estate and i stuck with a problem in my website. I want to add a page specific menu for page navigation with icon like 99acres.com and I am unable to understand which plugin is to be used. Please provide a better solution to me.
[image: I want to add the navigation menu like this]

Comment: Not sure there is a plugin for this.  I personally would write some custom CSS in the theme, but I guess you aren't using a custom theme.

Comment: Some themes do support this feature. other option will be to create menus and add them using php Conditional Statements. May be switch will be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

First add this in function.php file. This is font-awesome cdn

```
function wp_enqueue_icon_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style( 'fontawesome', 'http:////maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_icon_stylesheet' );
```

Then add this class 'fa fa-lg fa-home' in specific menu from backend menu

## Appreance->menus

Then  select the screen-option from top left and select/check the 'CSS Classes'

After that put the 'fa fa-lg fa-home' in one selected menu 'CSS Classes (optional)' field and save it

refresh the url.

## For more icons https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/

Comment: thank you for your reply , but i want to built a custom sticky navigation menu for a specific template . I had tried the method you provide but it add the menu in sidebar. It can't help me. Please provide me another solution.